# Linux configuration: How do I assign shortcuts to open applications?

Tags: gnome

As my first post in this forum recource I would like to ask a linux question. Also, this is something that I thought would be super straight forward, especially considering linux...

**The Situation:**
I can't find a way to use shortcuts to directly open applications in GNOME.

I really enjoy this functionality when using windows7 and would like to forward it into my ubuntu 10.10 partition. I noticed that ubuntu doesnt use the windows key that I have on my laptop keyboard...so I figured that it would be the perfect key to do such shortcuts for it wont overload any other shortcuts offered by ubuntu or most other applications.

In the end I'm trying to acheive this...

"super+a" opens Terminal.
"super+b" opens Firefox.
...etc

It's the only convenience I found out of native windows7 functions!

**Has anybody found a fairly straightforward way to accomplish this?**

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: True, or Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Ubuntu 10.10 (I'm using 12.04), so I might be a bit off on where the shortcuts can be found.

Go to

```
System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
```

where you will find all keyboard shortcuts for default actions. 
You can add shortcuts to start your favorite applications or scripts at the bottom.